# Looping through a column to make a new table in R

Tags: r

I want to make a table called Count_Table and in it, Id like to count the number of 0s, 1s, and 5s when column "num" == 1,2,3,4, etc.

For example, the code below will count the 0s,1s,and 5s in column "num" when "num == "1". This is great but i need to do this 34 more times since "num" goes from 1-35.

```
Count_Table <- table(SASS_data[num == "1"]$Visited5)
```

I am new to R and I don't know how to add 1 to the "num" and loop it until 35 so that the Count_Table includes the counts of 0,1,5 for all nums that exist (1-35). I am sorry if this is confusing and thank you for your help.

Comment: hi Callahan and welcome to the site. This is indeed confusing, could you post a sample of your data and your wanted output. It will make it a lot easier to help out :)

Comment: [See here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5963269/5325862) on making a reproducible example that is easier for folks to help with. That includes a sample of data, because right now it's unclear exactly what you're trying to do, but there are almost certainly questions already on SO that should help

Comment: Also your description says you want to count frequencies of values in num based on num, but your code shows you counting frequencies of values in Visited based on num. I imagine what you actually want is the latter

Answer (score 0):

`lapply` will generate a list of tables that span the columns of a dataframe.  E.g.,

```
tablist <- lapply(mtcars, table)
```

If your dataframe contains columns you want to exclude, can do that by restricting the dataframe.  E.g.,

```
tablist2 <- lapply(mtcars[, c(2, 4, 7)], table)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Answer**

Table works on multiple dimensions. Just put both `num` and `Visited5` as arguments. This also works if not all unique values of `Visited5` are present in every level of `num`, those cells will simply be set to `0`.

**Example**

```r
SASS_data <- data.frame(
  num = rep(1:5, each = 5),
  Visited5 = sample(1:3, 25, r = T)
)
table(SASS_data$num, SASS_data$Visited5)

#    1 2 3
#  1 2 1 2
#  2 1 3 1
#  3 1 1 3
#  4 2 0 3
#  5 2 2 1
```